# Are the solutions of the Euler Lagrange equation OPTIMAL

Tags: optimization, variational-analysis

my question is are the solutions of the Euler -Lagrange Equation always OPTIMAL , in the sense of the best solution

for example for the 'Brachistochrone' problem could exist a piecewise linear function (non differentiable) that gave an 'smaller' time to descend from point A to point B ??

and the same for Differential Geometry and minimal surfaces , could exist better solution to these problems ( in any spatial dimension) but these solutions do not follow Euler Lagrange Equation ?

Comment: The short answer is no.  Trivially, there are no minimiser of $I[y]:=\int_0^1 -y(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x$ but E-L gives $y=0$ which is actually a maximiser of $I$.